# naughty notifications with long messages

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

Is there a way to bypass the character limit of naughty's notification messages? I don't know what that limit is, but they seem to be getting truncated after a certain length. I'm using orglendar and it summarizes my google calendar events in one message/pane, which is very convenient.

Problem is if I have more than 4 or so events, they tend to get too long and get cut off. The resulting message ends up being somewhat unreadable due to incorrect parsing because of truncated `</span>` tags.

Alternatively, since notification messages probably weren't designed for long lists like this to begin with, is there an alternative widget that I could modify orglendar to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the orglendar code](https://github.com/alexander-yakushev/Orglendar/blob/awesome-3.4.x/orglendar.lua), it seems you could simply tweek the `calendar_width` variable at the top of the script to a larger value.

Alternatively, [the naughty documentation](https://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/naughty.html) tells that you can use a `nil` width to get automatic width. If this is what you want, you can simply change orglendar to reflect this. At the bottom of the orglendar.lua file (line 268), simply comment-out or remove the width parameter:

```
calendar = naughty.notify({ title = header,
                           text = cal_text,
                           timeout = 0, hover_timeout = 0.5,
                           -- width = calendar_width * char_width,
                           screen = mouse.screen,
                        })
```